# Error in checking if email exists in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for the poor formatting but can anyone help me. I am first checking if the email exists in the database. This is where my problem is occuring. Everything else works fine except $checkemail.

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)) {
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "charlieroth", "Charlie123", "betausersdb");
   if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
       die("Error Connecting To Database");
   }

   $checkemail = "SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";
   $query = mysqli_query($checkemail);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
       // do nothing
   } else {
       if (validateEmail($_POST['email'])) {
           $addEmail = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."')";
           mysqli_query($link, $addEmail);
           // add email
       }
   }
}

function validateEmail($useremail) {
    if (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]+)@([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]{2,})(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $useremail)) {
        // echo "Invalid Email";
        return false;
    } else {
        $domain = array('umich.edu');
        list(, $user_domain) = explode('@', $useremail, 2);
        return in_array($user_domain, $domain);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Have you checked `mysqli_error()`, ie. `mysqli_query($link, $addEmail) or die(mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail?

Comment: @Sean I honestly don't know where to include that. I am a beginner with PHP and MySQL

Comment: you are missing a 1st param in `list(, $user_domain)`

Comment: best way to do this is, define email as unique in database. and just try to insert it. after insert query check for error.

Comment: Check the edit I said that the wrong query wasn't working. I am refering to $checkemail not working. Sorry

Comment: Well, if `$checkemail` doesn't work, the use `mysqli_error()` on the query -> `$query = mysqli_query($link, $checkemail) or die(mysqli_error($link));` to get why the query is failing. This is debugging 101.

Comment: You are missing the `$link` as the 1st param in `mysqli_query($checkemail);`. Should be `$query = mysqli_query($link, $checkemail);`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your first mysqli_query. Do this:

```
<?php

      function validateEmail($useremail) {
          if (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]+)@([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]{2,})(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $useremail)) {
              // echo "Invalid Email";
              return false;
          } else {
              $domain = array('umich.edu');
              list(, $user_domain) = explode('@', $useremail, 2);
              return in_array($user_domain, $domain);
         }
    }   

    $mail = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)) :
          $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "charlieroth", "Charlie123", "betausersdb");
           if ( $link ) :
             $checkemail = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE email  = '$mail' ";
             $query = mysqli_query($link, $checkemail );
             if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                       // do nothing
             } 
             else {
                   if (validateEmail($mail) {
                       $addEmail = "INSERT INTO 'users' (email) VALUES ($mail)";
                       mysqli_query($link, $addEmail);
                       // add email
                   }
            }
          }

           else :
              echo 'Error';

           endif;


    endif;
?>
```

Comment: So there is no issue with `list(, $user_domain)`? (see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253759/error-in-checking-if-email-exists-in-mysql-database#comment60137261_36253759))

Comment: Can you use semi-colon notation like that in PHP? I'm just asking I didn't know

Comment: No. If you use $query = mysqli_query($checkemail); you need to connect also with your current open connection. You have tu use $query = mysqli_query($link,$checkemail); Also, you have to use  ' ' and not ` ` into php while query data from your database.

Comment: No my emails wont submit to the database with this code up top

Comment: @CharlesRoth using `if:`/`else:` is called [`alternative syntax`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: @FernandoUrban `SELECT * FROM 'users' ...` is Wrong. Quotes `'` are used for string literals, not for table/column names. Those either need to be unquoted, or with backticks `\`users\``.

Comment: I did it that way because I did not want to take the trouble to clean your dirty code (with all respect). Moreover, it is important that you review this line:

 $addEmail = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."')";
I say this because it also depends on how many columns you're using in your table in the database, if you have any ID that autoincremente or not. Similarly I corrected the code and put it up. May you take the trouble to even try.

Comment: I'm trying to help you to solve your problem, but if you don't want to listen alternative solutions to solve it, my help finish at this moment. Good bye.

Comment: @FernandoUrban I have been trying so please calm down